# Cannot access server SSH from terminal

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

Ok, so I've recently purchased a new domain and setup hosting for it. I've enabled SSH for the domain and have created public and private keys. I'm using terminal on a mac to try to connect. However, I keep getting this error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I've tried to troubleshoot the issue with the hosting provider, but they've rendered useless yet again. Here is the verbose response that I'm getting:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/kylebebeau/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to theinitgroup.com [72.34.33.171] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/kylebebeau/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/kylebebeau/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/kylebebeau/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/kylebebeau/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I'm lost with where to start on troubleshooting this. I've read up on the issue, and have run through various attempts to resolve this, but haven't gotten anywhere. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. You could try servefault or superuser.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I'll post my issue there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just needed to add my ip to the hosts.access file.